# Как реализовать поблочную прокрутку и блокировать событие скролла пока идет прокрутка?

Tags: javascript, html, css, прокрутка

Пытаюсь реализовать поблочную верстку.

Предусмотрел направление движения.
Предусмотрел крайние положения, т.е. докрутил до конца блок, сайт дальше начинает крутиться хоть вверх, хоть вниз.

Не могу победить момент, когда быстро вверх и вниз покрутишь мышкой и все сбивается, то есть блоки может разорвать, например показывать половину одного блока и другого.

Пробовал добавлять функции `throlle` (она просто откладывает прокрутку, не тот эффект в принципе) и `debouce` тоже у меня как-то не отработал, может я что-то неправильно делал

```js
const wrapper = document.querySelector(".wrapper");

let direction = "";

const scrollHeight = wrapper.scrollHeight;
const elemHeight = wrapper.clientHeight;
const lineHeight = scrollHeight - elemHeight;


wrapper.onwheel = (e) => {
//console.log(wrapper.scrollTop)
    // Определения направления скролла
    if (e.deltaY > 0) {
      direction = "down";
    } else if (e.deltaY < 0) {
      direction = "up";
    }
  
    // Прокрутка блока в зависимости от положения скролла и направления движения
    if (wrapper.scrollTop === 0) {
      (direction === "down") ? scrollAnimate(10) : () => {};
    } else if (Math.floor(wrapper.scrollTop) === lineHeight) {
      (direction === "up") ? scrollAnimate(-10) : () => {};
    } else if (Math.floor(wrapper.scrollTop) < lineHeight) {
      e.preventDefault();
      (direction === "up") ? scrollAnimate(-10) : scrollAnimate(10);
    }
  }
  
 function scrollAnimate (num) {
  let counter = 1;
  const timer = setInterval( function () {
    wrapper.scrollTop = wrapper.scrollTop + num;
    counter++;
    if (counter > 30) {
      clearInterval(timer)
    }
  }, 10)
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 600px;
  height: 340px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background: gray;
  padding: 0;
}

.item {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  display: block;
}

.list {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.red {
  background: red
}

.green {
  background: green
}

.blue {
  background: blue
}

.yellow {
  background: yellow
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="item red">1</li>
    <li class="item green">2</li>
    <li class="item yellow">3</li>
    <li class="item blue">4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Может конечно готовые есть какие-то решения, но я их не пробовал искать, хотел свой велосипед изобрести, попрактиковаться.

Как сделать так, чтобы пока анимация прокрутки прошла, скролл не действовал?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно создать булевскую переменную, в которую записывать, идет ли у нас анимация скролла. Если анимация идет, то ничего не предпринимать.

Пример реализации.

```js
const wrapper = document.querySelector(".wrapper");

let direction = "";
// Флаг, отвечающий за состояние скролинга
let isScrolling = false;

const scrollHeight = wrapper.scrollHeight;
const elemHeight = wrapper.clientHeight;
const lineHeight = scrollHeight - elemHeight;


wrapper.onwheel = (e) => {
  // если скролл идет, отменяем событие скролла и ничего не делаем
  if (isScrolling) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return;
  }
  //console.log(wrapper.scrollTop)
  // Определения направления скролла

  if (e.deltaY > 0) {
    direction = "down";
  } else if (e.deltaY < 0) {
    direction = "up";
  }

  // Прокрутка блока в зависимости от положения скролла и направления движения
  if (wrapper.scrollTop === 0) {
    (direction === "down") ? scrollAnimate(10): () => {};
  } else if (Math.floor(wrapper.scrollTop) === lineHeight) {
    (direction === "up") ? scrollAnimate(-10): () => {};
  } else if (Math.floor(wrapper.scrollTop) < lineHeight) {
    e.preventDefault();
    (direction === "up") ? scrollAnimate(-10): scrollAnimate(10);
  }
}

function scrollAnimate(num) {
  let counter = 1;
  isScrolling = true;
  const timer = setInterval(function() {
    wrapper.scrollTop = wrapper.scrollTop + num;
    counter++;
    if (counter > 30) {
      isScrolling = false;
      clearInterval(timer)
    }
  }, 10)
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 600px;
  height: 340px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background: gray;
  padding: 0;
}

.item {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  display: block;
}

.list {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.red {
  background: red
}

.green {
  background: green
}

.blue {
  background: blue
}

.yellow {
  background: yellow
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="item red">1</li>
    <li class="item green">2</li>
    <li class="item yellow">3</li>
    <li class="item blue">4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```